# How can I detect if a selector clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to detect if a jQuery-selector clicked. i mean:

```
var elem = 'foo'
var action = $(elem ).mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css('background-image',url(elem +'.png'))
});
var elem = 'bar'
//do the same action with new elem
var elem = 'blah'
//do the same action with new elem
```

the problem is how can i shorten this code to one line:

```
$('.far').mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('background-image',url(far.png'))});
$('.foooo').mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('background-image',url(foooo.png'))});
$('.bar').mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('background-image',url(bar.png'))});
$('.some').mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('background-image',url(some.png'))});
```

Comment: So is your problem "How can I detect if a selector clicked?

" OR "how can i shorten this code to one line:" ??

Comment: You want click `event` or `mouseenter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making this array

```
var arr = [ "far", "foooo", "bar", "some" ];
arr.forEach( function( item ){
    $('.' + item ).mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('background-image','url('+ item +'.png'))});
    //adding the click detection as well
    $('.' + item ).click(function(){$(this).css('background-image','url('+ item +'.png'))});
});
```

Comment: the same as above. Just a hover, not click detection

Comment: @alpham8 click detection is added, however OP's question is not about that. Read the question carefully.

Comment: @alpham8 Also discouraging someone while helping is not a good thing to appreciate. Upvoted this answer.

Comment: the question headline is about this.

Comment: @ANS thanks +1 for you as well. Alpham8 - you need to read the whole question carefully.

Comment: yeah ok, next time I will not answer on not clearified questions. Also that this answer solves the question shows me that it is not clearified what the author really needs.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', 'div[data-background]', function() {
    $(this).css({'background' : 'url('+$(this).data('background')+')',});
  });
});
```

```css
div {
    width : 500px;
    height : 320px;
    border : 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div data-background="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/04/14/23/peacock-2201428_960_720.jpg"></div>
  
  <div data-background="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/18/59/peacock-154128_960_720.png"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this detects not, if an div is clicked. This is just a hover

Comment: @alpham8 Op doen't need a click detection. Anyway if OP wants that he can simply replace mouseenter with click. Upvoted this

Answer (score 1):

Works only in this situation.

Since you have single class selector,assuming you don't have multiple classes

```
$('.far','.foooo','.bar','.some').mouseenter(function(){
 var selector = $(this).attr('class');
 $(this).css('background-image',url(selector+'.png'));
});
```

Comment: also not click detecting

Comment: @alpham8 What do you mean by click ? OP refereed  click as an example for event. He meant for detecting selector on mouse over.

Comment: @Mohammad Agree with you Mohammad. Just pointed the same to OP in first line of my answer :)

Answer (score -3):

You need something like this:

```
$(".foo").click(function (event) {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

Again, you need click, not mouseenter. Because mouseenter is just a hover, which you could do with plain css.

Comment: -1. you have to understand the point that OP wants to get the selected elements class to  refactor his/her code. Not at all related to events